# Comparison of 1D and 2D Array Size in C

Tags: c

In C an array like `int a[4]` creates 5 locations to store integers including `a[0]` to `a[4]`.

But in case of a 2D array like `int a[2][2]` is producing only four locations and not 3*3 = 9 locations. What is the reason for this?

Comment: as above, how are you  measuring 5?

Comment: (1) No; the definition `int a[4];` creates 4 locations `a[0]` .. `a[3]`.   You can form the address of `&a[4]` (e.g. `a + 4`) for comparisons, but you can't legitimately dereference that address.   (2) The size of the 2D array size is consistent with the size of the 1D array.

Comment: If you try to access `a[4]` after defining `int a[4]` you will probably not get an error directly but this is indeed an `off-by-one` error that will in the long run cause you trouble since `int a[4]` is an array of 4 elements (0, 1, 2, 3) and not 5 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4).

Comment: When I see questions like this, I wonder if it is a bot, a troll, or a trollbot.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've seen worse today...

Comment: Arrays in C are indexed starting from 0 to n-1 ( n being the size of the array)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid premise: in C, an array `int a[4]` creates 4 locations, not 5. If you're using `a[4]` afterwards, you're invoking undefined behavior via buffer overruns. The 2D array behavior is as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of 1D array is incorrect. `int a[4]` reserves location for for `4` ints and NOT `5` ints.

i.e. `int a[4]` reserves memory for `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]`.

In case of 2D array, total elements is given by `num of rows * num of columns`, so yes `a[2][2]` contains 4 integers. So it reserves memory for 4 integers.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is right.. I did not sleep well for 3 days. I'm forgetting things. This is such a blunder I asked. :-)